Probability that an event occurs before another event in a sequence of trials.
Consider a sequence of 10 independent trials, where in each trial, we roll three identical and fair dice simultaneously. Calculate the probability that a trial with a total sum of 7 on the three dice appears before a trial with a total sum of 5.
I understand that the problem is about a sequence of 10 trials, illustrated by an example like $\textbf{x77x5xx57x}$, where:

x: represents a trial that does not result in a total of 5 or 7.
5: represents a trial that has a total of 5.
7: represents a trial that has a total of 7.

The question is whether the problem aims for the scenario where in all 10 trials, case 1: the total of 7 appears before the total of 5, and the total of 5 appears before the total of 7 simultaneously (e.g., $\textbf{x7x5x5x7xx}$), or case 2: only the totals of 7 appear before the totals of 5 (e.g., $\textbf{7x777x5x5x}$).
I am struggling with case 1 and have tried to resolve case 2 as follows:
$p_1$ is the event where the trial results in a total of 7 without any total of 5 appearing. $p_2$ is the event where the trial results in a total of 5 without any total of 7 appearing.
In this case,   $ \ P(p_1) = \dfrac{1}{14}$ and $P(p_2) = \dfrac{6}{201}.$
In this case, $C$ is the probability we need to calculate; $C_i$ ​ is the probability that in the first $i$ trials, there is a trial that results in $p_2$ ​ , and in the remaining $10−i$ trials, there is a trial that results in $p_2$.
$$P(C) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{9} P(C_i) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{9}\bigg[1-\bigg(\dfrac{13}{14} \bigg)\bigg]\bigg[(1-\bigg(\dfrac{195}{201} \bigg)\bigg] = 0.288...$$
Have I solved it correctly, and is there a solution for the two cases mentioned?

This is the type of problem where it helps to have intuition.  You can ignore any roll where the sum is not 5 or 7.
Theoretically, this problem becomes a Stars and Bars problem.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
this article and
this article.
However, in this case it is much easier to list the satisfying rolls:
To roll a $~5,~$ the first roll must be $~k \in \{1,2,3\}.~$
Then, there are $~(4-k)~$ possibilities for the next two rolls.
So, the number of satisfying 5-rolls are $~3 + 2 + 1 = 6.~$
To roll a $~7,~$ the first roll must be $~k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}.~$
Then, there are $~(6-k)~$ possibilities for the next two rolls.
So, the number of satisfying 7-rolls are $~5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15.~$
Therefore, the probability of rolling where the three dice sum to 7 before rolling where the three dice sum to 5 is
$$\frac{15}{15 + 6}.$$
However, the above computation assumes that there are an infinite number of rolls.  Since there are only $~10~$ rolls, you must scale the computation by the probability that there was at least one sum-7 or sum-5 among the $~10~$ rolls.
Therefore, the final computation is
$$\left[ 1 - \left( ~\frac{216 - 21}{216} ~\right)^{10} ~\right] \times \frac{15}{15 + 6}.$$
One slightly different viewpoint is that first you have to compute the probability that there was at least one sum-7 or one sum-5.  Then, you are only concerned about the very first such sum-7 or sum-5.

one more thing about the below computation, if there is only one 5 rolls and nine others aren't 7 rolls, does the event that needs to be calculated include this case?

@kukuouk That is already included in my computation.  Please re-read the very last paragraph of my answer.  The second factor of $~\dfrac{15}{15 + 6}~$ requires that the very first [sum-7 or sum-5] roll actually be a sum-7 roll.
